# UV unwrapping how to seperate seams

Tags: uv

How do I separate them like romeo and juliet
[image]

I have selected the middle with alt and marked seam, but they don't seem separated?

Comment: so you must not have separated the two parts

Comment: So i select again and unwrap?

Comment: perhaps share your file to see what went wrong: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I found the reason, somehow I pressed O and it can be separated, proportional editing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was that you had activated the *Proportional Editing* mode (which allows you to select the closest vertices), just deactivate it.

[image]